# I can't get / route to work in Slim 3

Tags: php, .htaccess, slim, slim-3

I have 2 slim projects in my root directory. All of my routes work except for my / route. It doesn't understand where "home" is. I am using a virtual server on an as400 ibm I, so I'm not using virtual hosts because I don't understand how to make that work in my environment. Instead I have 2 directory instructions.

```
  13       <Directory /www/payroll/htdocs/payroll/public>
  14            AllowOverride All
  15            Order Allow,Deny
  16            Allow from All
  17            DirectoryIndex index.php
  18       </Directory>
  19       
  20       <Directory /www/payroll/htdocs/bd/public>
  21            AllowOverride All
  22            Order Allow,Deny
  23            Allow from All
  24            DirectoryIndex index.php
  25       </Directory>
```

And my .htaccess looks like this.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]


RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}::$1 ^(/.+)(.+)::\2$
RewriteRule ^(.*) - [E=BASE:%1]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ %{ENV:BASE}index.php [NC,L]
</IfModule>
```

I'm sure if I should try to fix my .conf or my .htaccess? Or what to do so that Slim will see the directory that it is in.